# Sublime Text 2: How to reformat CSS to specific (non-standard) styles?

Tags: css, regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

There are multiple CSS formatters out there that will make this:

```
.classname {
  style: value;
  style: value;
}
.classname {
  style: value;
}
```

and turn it into this:

```
.classname { style: value; style: value; }
.classname { style: value; }
```

The problem is my personal preference doesn't fall in line with a lot of other people's preferences. That's fine because I'm not a common use-case so I don't expect there to be anything. I would like to take the first example, and turn it into this:

```
.classname {
  style: value;
  style: value;
}
.classname { style: value; }
```

Where all classes with multiple styles are on their own lines, but each class with just a single style is compact.

I can settle for some regex I can search in Sublime Text 2 that will let me find each instance of single style classes like that and just edit after the find to be what I want. That's perfectly fine with me and would help when I inherit large stylesheets. As you can probably imagine, I don't normally do it by hand for these large sheets and just have to live with it. I'd prefer to have a simple solution like searching a regex or something in the absence of a plugin.

Comment: I do my CSS this way as well, I never thought it was weird.

Comment: I don't think it's weird either but I never get a stylesheet that has it this way. It's always 5000 lines of the first example. It lead me to believe it's not as common a practice as I'd like.

Comment: Good question so far, but... can you please do the following homework: 1. add what exactly do you expect like `This is my CSS. I'd like to press a button somewhere and the buffer should look like that.` or `I'd like to select some lines, press a button ...`. 2. Think about if CSS reformatting is really worth the effort of building plugins or sophisticating RegEx' (on the other peoples preference: in a multi-developer project, when you one-click to reformat code you'll probably annoy everyone else. Please consider to change your mind and enforce a code styleguide everyone should obey).

Comment: Well like I said I don't expect there to be a plugin and I doubt there ever will be. So what I was asking for was a regex I can search for that will find each of those lines. As far as other people's preferences, I've been both involved in writing the guidelines and just following them in different jobs. To be honest, the personal responsibility of use is really outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Here's a nice primer for how to code CSS, http://cssguidelin.es/. Not saying anyone has to follow everything in it to the letter, just nice to see a baseline being established.

Comment: do you still keep declarations to one-line if you have to declare more than 5 properties?

Comment: @hungerstar Basically this guide you posted shows the preference I stated above http://cssguidelin.es/#multi-line-css All in all, I'm pretty against these types of things and think it should be left to teams to decide what their standards are. For example, there's going to be people who want to punch the author of this guide in the face for suggesting tabs instead of spaces as that's a common battlefield. It might as well go on to say all CSS should be written in Vim. That guide itself takes so many liberties. I, for one am greatly opposed to their one, two, or five new lines rule.

Comment: But thanks for posting it as some will like it no doubt.

Comment: @Sgnl I don't understand your question. I call a CSS declaration a property coupled with a value. Ie width: 10%; is a declaration, width is the property, and 10% is the value. I could even be wrong about the semantics of the terms but that's the way I always looked at them.

Comment: You are correct with your terms, I was incorrect. I forgot what I was going to follow through with.

Comment: @o_O I guess I should have left this part of my comment out, `"Not saying anyone has to follow everything in it to the letter."` LOL. Thanks for reading it though.

Answer (score 1):

The basic transform can be done with RegEx replacements. I'd do it this way:

**Step 1:** `\n` → *`NOTHING`*  *Remove all newlines*

**Step 2:** `[\s\t]{1,}` →   *Change multispace/tab top one space (possibly nice to have)*

**Step 3:** `\}` → `}`<kbd>NEWLINE</kbd> *Break after }*

**Step 4:** `\s+(\})|(\{)\s+` → `\1\2` *Remove single space before & after braces (possibly nice to have)*

There is no builtin functionality to create custom keybindings for search and replace, but there's a plugin that is able to do this:

https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace

> Reg Replace is a plugin for Sublime Text 2 that allows the creating of commands consisting of sequences of find and replace instructions.

A keybinding and RegReplace config might look like this...

**RegReplace**

```
{
    "replacements": {
        "strip_newlines": {
            "find": "\\n", "greedy": true, "case": false,
            "replace": ""
        },
        "reduce_multispace": {
            "find": "[\\s\\t]{1,}", "greedy": true, "case": false,
            "replace": ""
        },
        "break_after_closecurlybrace": {
            "find": "\\}", "greedy": true, "case": false,
            "replace": "\\}\n"
        },
        "strip_space_around_curlybraces": {
            "find": "\s+(\})|(\{)\s+", "greedy": true, "case": false,
            "replace": "\\1\\2"
        }
    }
}
```

**Keybindings**

```
{
    "caption": "Make my odd formatting",
    "command": "reg_replace",
    "args": {
        "replacements": ["strip_newlines", "reduce_multispace", "break_after_closecurlybrace", "strip_space_around_curlybraces"]
    }
}
```

*Both completely untested*

Comment: This is a great starting point. Thanks. It still doesn't differentiate between elements with multiple declarations but it's a place to start from.

Comment: I think writing a plugin a better approcach because you can do more specific things. Maybe there are standalone CSS formatting tools. The plugin could also run that tool and update the buffer with the reformatted CSS.